# Impose nesting limits on recursive data structure

Tags: haskell

Consider a recursive data structure like the following:

```
data Tree level
    = Leaf String
    | Node level [ Tree level ]
```

Now, if `level` is an instance of `Ord`, I would like to impose at the type level the following limitation on the data structure: a node must contain only `Tree`s with a higher `level`.

You can safely assume that `level` is a simple sum type like

```
Level
= Level1
| Level2
...
| LevelN
```

but where `N` is not known a priori. In this case I would be able to have that all the subnodes of a node have a higher level.

For example

```
tree = Node Level1
    [ Node Level2 []
    , Node Level3 []   
    ]
```

should compile, while

```
tree = Node Level2
    [ Node Level1 []
    ]
```

should not.

Is it possible to model such a thing in Haskell?

Comment: You will need GADTS. Check out this https://wiki.haskell.org/GADTs_for_dummies

Comment: It would be good if you could explain a bit more detailed what you would like to impose at the type level. Give some examples of what should and what shouldn't compile.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I edited the question providing some examples

Comment: @Euge could you please provide an example on how I could use GADTs in this case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So there are a number of difficulties with this question. Peano numbers are a good place to start, though:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds                 #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs                     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators             #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds           #-}

data Nat = Z | S Nat
```

Next, we'll need some way of saying one number is "bigger" than another. We can do so by first defining an inductive class for "n is less than or equal to m"

```
class (n :: Nat) <= (m :: Nat)
instance Z <= n
instance n <= m => (S n <= S m)
```

We can then define "less than" in terms of this:

```
type n < m = S n <= m
```

Finally, here's the Tree and Levels:

```
data Tree n where
  Leaf :: String -> Tree n
  Node :: n < z => Level z -> [Tree z] -> Tree n

data Level n where
  Level0 :: Level Z
  Level1 :: Level (S Z)
  Level2 :: Level (S (S Z))
  Level3 :: Level (S (S (S Z)))
  Level4 :: Level (S (S (S (S Z))))
```

And, as desired, the first example compiles:

```
tree = Node Level1
    [ Node Level2 []
    , Node Level3 []   
    ]
```

While the second does not:

```
tree = Node Level2
    [ Node Level1 []
    ]
```

Just for extra fun, we can now add a "custom type error" (this will need `UndecidableInstances`:

```
import GHC.TypeLits (TypeError, ErrorMessage(Text))

instance TypeError (Text "Nodes must contain trees of a higher level") => S n < Z
```

So when you write:

```
tree = Node Level2
    [ Node Level1 []
    ]
```

You get the following:

> • Nodes must contain trees of a higher level
>
> • In the expression: Node Level1 []
>
> In the second argument of ‘Node’, namely ‘[Node Level1 []]’
>
> In the expression: Node Level2 [Node Level1 []]

If you want to make "level" more generic, you'll need a couple more extensions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications, RankNTypes, AllowAmbiguousTypes, TypeFamilies #-}
import qualified GHC.TypeLits as Lits

data Level n where
  Level0 :: Level Z
  LevelS :: !(Level n) -> Level (S n)
    
class HasLevel n where level :: Level n
instance HasLevel Z where level = Level0
instance HasLevel n => HasLevel (S n) where level = LevelS level
    
type family ToPeano (n :: Lits.Nat) :: Nat where
  ToPeano 0 = Z
  ToPeano n = S (ToPeano (n Lits.- 1))
    
node :: forall q z n m. (ToPeano q ~ z, HasLevel z, n < z) => [Tree z] -> Tree n
node = Node level
    
tree =
    node @1
      [ node @2 []
      , node @3 []   
      ]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, very nice answer. I had to modify it slightly to ensure that a level could not be contained in itself using `Node :: Plus n m z => Level z -> [Tree ('S z)] -> Tree n`

Answer (score 10):

Here's the basic idea. The easiest way to encode recursion limits like this is to use [Peano numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms). Let's define such a type.

```
data Number = Zero | Succ Number
```

A number is either zero or the successor of another number. This is a nice way to define numbers here, as it will get along nicely with our tree recursion. Now, we want the `Level` to be a type, not a value. If it's a value, we can't limit its value at the type level. So we use GADTs to restrict the way we can initialize things.

```
data Tree (lvl :: Number) where
    Leaf :: String -> Tree lvl
    Node :: [Tree lvl] -> Tree ('Succ lvl)
```

`lvl` is the depth. A `Leaf` node can have any depth, but a `Node` node is restricted in its depth and must be strictly greater than that of its children (here, strictly one greater, which works in most simple cases. Allowing it to be strictly greater in general would require some more complicated type-level tricks, possibly with `-XTypeInType`). Notice that we use `'Succ` at the type level. This is a *promoted type*, enabled with `-XDataKinds`. We also need `-XKindSignatures` to enable the `:: Number` constraint.

Now let's write a function.

```
f :: Tree ('Succ 'Zero) -> String
f _ = "It works!"
```

This function only takes trees that go at most one level deep. We can try to call it.

```
f (Leaf "A") -- It works!
f (Node [Leaf "A"]) -- It works!
f (Node [Node [Leaf "A"]]) -- Type error
```

So it will fail at compile-time if the depth is too much.

Complete example (including compiler extensions):

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, KindSignatures, DataKinds #-}

data Number = Zero | Succ Number

data Tree (lvl :: Number) where
    Leaf :: String -> Tree lvl
    Node :: [Tree lvl] -> Tree ('Succ lvl)

f :: Tree ('Succ 'Zero) -> String
f _ = "It works!"
```

This isn't everything you can do with this. There's certainly expansions to be made, but it gets the point across and will hopefully point you in the right direction.

Comment: I think you got the OP direction wrong: "a node must contain only `Tree`s with a higher level" requires `'Succ` on the other side. I'd be temped to add a constructor `Higher :: Tree ('Succ lvl) -> Tree lvl` so to be able to represent "higher" instead of "+1" (at some cost, though). (Otherwise, we could also model the "higher" relation with another GADT...)